# why when I call java class from kotlin project program alway stop working

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

This is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         lateinit var maT : mat
         var num : Int = maT.two()
      }
}
```

And this is my java class

```
public class mat {

      public int two(){
        return 2;
      }
}
```

They are in the same package

Comment: You should read the error message. You're declaring `maT` as `lateinit` then you use it without initializing it.

Comment: you can't declare local variable lateinit (inside a function)

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring  because the **maT** property has not be initialised when you are calling

```
maT.two()
```

The documentation for **lateinit** states:

> Accessing a lateinit property before it has been initialized throws a special exception that clearly identifies the property being accessed and the fact that it hasn't been initialized.

In order to fix the problem try:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     var maT = mat()
     var num : Int = maT.two()
  }
}
```

The change that was made was to remove **lateinit** and to instantiate an object of type **mat** :

```
var maT = mat()
```

FYI: You should consider using a capital at the start of a class e.g. **Mat**